# Hibernate not batching inserts

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data, timescaledb

I hope you can help me with this problem since I'm really clueless by now and none of the related questions could help me so far.

I have a collection of entities I want to batch insert into TimescaleDB (extension of Postgresql) via spring-data saveAll() and I thought I configured everything by the book, but the hibernate stats never reflect a batch insert:

> 1223268 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
>
> 0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
>
> 34076442411 nanoseconds spent executing 3408 JDBC statements;
>
> 0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;

My Hibernate properties are configured via HibernatePropertiesCustomizer like this:

```
props.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", true);
props.put("hibernate.order_inserts", true);
props.put("hibernate.order_updates", true);
props.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "100");
```

I validated that a transaction context is indeed present during saveAll() by calling:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive()
```

And the entity's ID looks like this. There are no @GeneratedValue or @SequenceGenerator annotations, since I use the data's timestamp (from a web API) as the ID.

```
@Id
@Column
private Instant time;
```

I even tried by adapting my connection String to control the rewrite behavior, but it did not help:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db?reWriteBatchedInserts=true&currentSchema=finance-data
```

I tested this with both maven org.postgresql 42.2.9 and 42.2.13 drivers.
The Spring Boot release train version is the 2.2.2.RELEASE which bundles hibernate-core 5.4.9.FINAL and spring-jdbc 5.2.2.RELEASE.
The timescale docker version is 1.7.1-pg12.

Please let me know if you need any more additional information. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

From [this](https://persistencelayer.wixsite.com/springboot-hibernate/post/the-best-way-to-batch-inserts-via-saveall-iterable-s-entities), it mentions if the entity being batched inserted is manually assigned its ID , you have to add a `@Version` property. But for PostgreSQL , adding `@Version` is not required if using `SEQUENCE` generator to generate the ID.

I do not try if adding `@Version` can solve the problem if the ID is manually assigned but you could have a try. I personally use `SEQUENCE` generator to generate ID and it works without adding `@Version` in PostgreSQL.

And in order to generate ID effectively when using `SEQUENCE` generator , I also changed to use "pooled" or "pooled-lo" algorithm that is mentioned in [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/) to reduce the database round trip to get the ID.

Here are what I do :

```java
@Entity
public class Foo {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="foo_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="foo_sequence", sequenceName = "foo_id_seq", allocationSize = 100)
    private Long id;

}
```

And the hibernate setting :

```
hibernate.order_inserts = true
hibernate.order_updates = true
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 50
hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data = true

# For using "pool-lo" optimiser for generating ID when using JPA @SequenceGenerator
hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred = pooled-lo
```

And also need to make sure the sequence in PostreSQL is aligned with what is configured in `@SequenceGenerator` :

```sql
alter sequence foo_id_seq increment by 100;
```

For completeness , in case of PostgreSQL , also add `reWriteBatchedInserts=true` in the JDBC connection string which can provides 2-3x performance improvement which is said by the [docs](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am not sure how this can actually help me. I definitely do not want to create the IDs myself or let my database do it, since I prefer to use the financial data timestamps as PKs, which is also done in the official TimescaleDB examples. I will adapt my question since I have failed to mention that I use the timescale DB extention for postgresql!

Comment: well you can still make an id which is a surrogate ID , just for the internal use. You can still keep the existing timestamp for the client  use which is a kind of natural key/business key.For the client , they do not need to know the surrogate ID , and still keep using the exiting timestamp as a key as usual. Also hibernate also has @NaturalId to map such the natural id.

Comment: Tried: mysql; no `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` -- manual adding id; batch still doesnt work.