# Micronaut: configure JPA batch operations

Tags: jpa, micronaut, micronaut-data

I'm trying to configure my Micronaut project to insert/update using batch operations (create one single insert with 50 items included instead of 50 different inserts).

I cannot find a more detailed manual so the configuration that I'm using is this one:

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:postgresql:///postgres?cloudSqlInstance=uri&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&ipTypes=PRIVATE
    username: ****
    password: ****
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver

jpa:
  default:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: none
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 50
          order_inserts: true
          order_updates: true
        batch_versioned_data: true
        show_sql: false
```

This is the repo:

```
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Repository;
import io.micronaut.data.repository.GenericRepository;

@Repository
public interface ArticleExportPort extends GenericRepository<ArticleExport, Long> {
    void insertMany(Iterable<ArticleExport> articleExports);
    List<ArticleExport> findAll();
}
```

And this is the Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_EXPORT")
public class ArticleExport {
  @Id
  private Long Id;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID",nullable = false)
  private Long  productId;
}
```

The database is a PostgreSQL located in Google Cloud but also testing in local it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing that I see with your config is that `order_inserts` is in the wrong hierarchy. It shoud be `jpa.default.properties.hibernate.order_inserts` (same for order_updates).

What do you mean by it does not work? Is Hibernate creating for each entity instance a new insert statement instead of batching it?

Comment: Thanks for correcting the config but it is still not working.
Yes, because I'm printing the sql I can see in the logs that hibernate is generating a sql per insert instead of batching it.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/62245806/960875 ? Can you add your entity `ArticleExport` to the question, please?